What is the derivative of the $\ell_1$ norm of the matrix?
The question is short. I have a square matrix $W$. I know $\|W\|_1$ means the usual $\ell_1$ norm, which means the sum of the absolute value of elements of the matrix. Now I want to compute the derivative of  $\|W\|_1$ with respect to $W$. What is the solution?
The background of the question is that I want to do some optimization work in R by using optim function. I know what my objective function is. Basically it's the loss function plus the encouraging sparsity term.  Now I need to compute its gradient.

Take care : are you sure $|M|_1$ isn't for "matrix norm" 1, which isn't the same as the one you mention ?

@JeanMarie Thanks for remind. It's not matrix norm. The matrix is just a frame that combines all the elements. In my problem, I consider questions from all the elements.

The partial derivative of the absolute sum of a set of real numbers with respect to any of those numbers is $\pm1$ depending on the sign of that number. It is not partially differentiable with respect to a variable where that variable is $0$ (but the left and right partial derivatives are $-1$ and $1$).
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{kl}}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|x_{ij}|=\hbox{sign}(x_{kl})$$
